# Is "Detection for corruption in HTTP and FTP" question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Is [Detection for corruption in HTTP and FTP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/detection-for-corruption-in-http-and-ftp) question on-topic at IT Security SE?

I fail to see how this question falls under one of the categories described in the [What topics can I ask about here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Should this question be migrated to Super User SE or it is on-topic here?

Comment: Agreed. Assuming we understood it correctly... I closed and migrated.

Comment: @AviD, it looks like mods at Network Engineering put the question on hold. Probably, the Super User was a correct destination to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was migrated to [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) <del>because it is on-topic there.</del>

<del>and put on hold by the Moderator.</del>
and closed by the Moderator.